# How to install nemo-terminal on Linux Pop! Os 22.04

Tags: pop-os, nemo

I am trying to install `nemo-terminal` on `Linux pop-os 6.0.12-76060006-generic`. I used the command:

```
sudo apt install nemo-terminal
```

but I got the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package nemo-terminal
```

Any help installing it

Comment: It seems that `nemo-terminal` is the terminal embedded in nemo file manager. Do you want to install the nemo file manager or the terminal provided by cinnamon desktop?

Comment: i have nemo installed on my pop os. It is my fav file manager because of F3 (split to two dirs). I cannot download plugins from Nemo itself.

Comment: Have you already added the nemo repository? (ppa:webupd8team/nemo)

Comment: i tried but didn't work. looks most of them old

Answer (score 0):

the ppa was already mentioned, just for the sake of completeness:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo-terminal
```

---

If it doesn't work, maybe get it from [its GitHub repository](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions)?

First, you should install `mint-dev-tools` before building the nemo extension (hopefully Pop Os has this program in its repositories).

After you have installed `mint-dev-tools` you should run the following:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions.git
cd nemo-extensions
./build nemo-terminal
```

Credits to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/827682/1086345)

Comment: E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/nemo/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package nemo-terminal

Comment: For the second method:
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: Ok, maybe try:
1. suppose you are on a 64 bit system, go to the repo directly:
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/nemo/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nemo-terminal/?C=M;O=D

2. download the latest amd64 (for 64 bit system):
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/nemo/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nemo-terminal/nemo-terminal_3.0.1-1~webupd8~xenial0_amd64.deb

3. go to directory and try: sudo apt install nemo-terminal_3.0.1-1_webupd8_xenial0_amd64

4. which error do you get? You should usually see now the conflicting packages

Comment: @AKMalkadi I've updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package mint-dev-tools
many thanks for your efforts. I gave up installing it